# How to put results from database in a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public List<ColorModel> getAllColor() {
  String query = "SELECT * FROM COLOR";
  List<ColorModel> colors = getjdbcTemplate().query(query, new ColorMapper());
  return colors;
}

class ColorMapper implements RowMapper<Color> {
  public ColorModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    ColorModel color = new ColorModel ();
    color.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    color.setName(rs.getString("color_name"));
  }
}
```

**Question**

How can I rather return a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>` rather than `List<ColorModel>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can easily just perform the mapping after you've fetched the results as a list:

```
...
List<Color> colors = getjdbcTemplate().query(query, new ColorMapper());
Map<Integer, String> colorMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
for (Color color : colors) {
    colorMap.put(color.getId(), color.getName());
}
return colorMap;
```

Alternatively, you could provide a `RowCallbackHandler`:

```
final Map<Integer, String> colorMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new RowCallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) {
        colorMap.put(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("color_name"));
    }
});
```

Note that you can't create a `Map<int, String>` in Java, as generic type arguments can't be primitive types.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. it is suppose to be `color`. I was trying to avoid iterative over the list again to created HashMap but rather do that while fetching the query..

Comment: Thanks that works. I just had to wrap it around with sqlexception

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<ColorModel> getAllColor() {
Map<Integer,String> map = LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();    
  String query = "SELECT * FROM COLOR";
  List<Color> colors = getjdbcTemplate().query(query, new ColorMapper());
  for (Color color : colors) {
    colorMap.put(color.getId(), color.getName());
}
return map;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to make the map an instance variable? It looks like it should be declared within the method to me.